# android sqlite unique insert

Tags: android, sqlite, unique-constraint

Just a simple SQLite question...

I've created a table like this:`CREATE TABLE mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, column1 TEXT, column2 TEXT, UNIQUE (column1, column2))`
(I also tried it with the extension `ON CONFLICT REPLACE`)

But if I call my insert method on the second time with the same values, they will be added. E.g.

```
insert("one", "two"); 
insert("one", "two");
```

fills the table like this:

```
1 | one | two
2 | one | two
```

but it should look like this after the second call:

```
1 | one | two
```

That's my insert function:

```
public void insert(String a, String b){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("column1", a);
    contentValues.put("column2", b);
    try {
        //database.insertWithOnConflict("mytable", null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
        //database.insertWithOnConflict("mytable", null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        database.insertOrThrow("mytable", null, contentValues);
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        Log.e("insert", "SQLException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

if I call

```
insert("one", "two"); 
insert("three", "two");
```

the table should be filled like this:

```
1 | one | two
2 | three | two
```

Comment: this is hardly related to android. did you try to reproduce the issue on a regular sqlite db?

Comment: are you sure your database is actually declared like that? it could be that you use another definition, but did not re-created the table?

Comment: you can publish the select query?. try adding "_" to id. I mean when you create the tabala _id

Comment: I didn't reproduce it on a regular sqlite db... but the table is recreated with this create statement, I uninstalled the application. It doesn't matter if I use  the internal "_id" or the created "id". I selected all values to check the correct insert by `Cursor cursor = database.query("mytable", new String[]{"column1", "column2"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: mostly it works with the extension "ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK". But it's strange: if I try to insert a lot of rows twice, on the second time the last nearly twenty datasets are inserted without throwing a constraint exception although there has to be one. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to write UNIQUE with each column in the table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, column1 TEXT UNIQUE IGNORE, column2 TEXT UNIQUE IGNORE)
```

ignore is to, ignore the value that is not unique

> When an applicable constraint violation occurs, the IGNORE resolution algorithm skips the one row that contains the constraint violation and continues processing subsequent rows of the SQL statement as if nothing went wrong. Other rows before and after the row that contained the constraint violation are inserted or updated normally. No error is returned when the IGNORE conflict resolution algorithm is used.

**As You have updated your question**
what you have to do is to remove UNIQUE AND IGNORE FROM COLUMN in which you need duplicated values.

hope that helps.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention that I only want to ignore if ALL unique columns are the same. If only one of the columns has another value, they should be inserted. (look at my edit part...)

Comment: @lis for that what you can do is to merge two columns in to one and then apply that unique and ignore constraint.

Comment: I don't understand how the create statement should look like... `CREATE TABLE mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, column1 TEXT UNIQUE IGNORE, column2 TEXT UNIQUE IGNORE)` causes an `SQLiteException`